# Keep object in array which has the highest value but remove all the objects that have duplicate value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects. I want to keep the object which has the highest value but remove any duplicates.

For example, in the following array of objects, I want to remove the object that has a duplicate price and keep the one with the highest value. -

```
const data = [{
    "title": "The Little Prince",
    "price": 49,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "title": "Watchmen",
    "price": 49,
    "value": "40"
  }
]

/**
const desiredOutput = [
  {
     "title":"Watchmen",
     "price": 49,
     "value": 40
  }
] 
**/
```

Here's my code but it doesn't remove the object with the same price and outputs the same array -

```js
const data = [{
    "title": "The Little Prince",
    "price": 49,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "title": "Watchmen",
    "price": 49,
    "value": "40"
  }
]

const removeDuplicatePrice = plans => {
  const prices = [];
  const updatedBooks = plans.filter(el => {
    const matchingRack = prices.find(
      element =>
      element.price === el.price
    );
    let {
      price,
      value
    } = el;

    if (!matchingRack) {
      prices.push({
        price,
        value
      });
      return true;
    }

    if (el.value > matchingRack.value) {
      matchingRack.value = el.value;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  return updatedBooks;
};

console.log(removeDuplicatePrice(data));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can index by the `price` property. The `price` number in the object will hold the current largest value object for that given price. If your current object you are iterated on has a higher `value`, you can update the indexed value for that price to hold the new object. You can get the `Object.values()` of your accumulated object to get the unique objects.

See example below:

```js
const data = [{ "title": "The Little Prince", "price": 49, "value": 20 }, { "title": "Watchmen", "price": 49, "value": 40 } ];

const res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const curr = acc[obj.price];
  acc[obj.price] = curr ? (curr.value < obj.value ? obj : curr) : obj;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Or using an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) might be a more appropriate option to use with `.reduce()`:

```js
const data = [{ "title": "The Little Prince", "price": 49, "value": 20 }, { "title": "Watchmen", "price": 49, "value": 40 } ];

const res = Array.from(data.reduce((m, obj) => {
  const curr = m.get(obj.price);
  return m.set(obj.price, curr ? (curr.value < obj.value ? obj : curr) : obj);
}, new Map).values());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to remove duplicates from current array:

```js
const data = [{
    "title": "The Little Prince",
    "price": 49,
    "value": "20"
  },
  {
    "title": "Watchmen",
    "price": 49,
    "value": "40"
  }
]

let result = data.reduce((state, current) => {
   let prevIndex = state.findIndex(x => x.price === current.price);
   if(prevIndex === -1){
       state.push(current);
   }
   else if(state[prevIndex].value < current.value){
       state[prevIndex] = current;
   }
   return state;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```